# Applying Classes Conditionally in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I am trying to apply the class `active` if `commentBadgeActive` is true.The image `Scholar` should change from grayscale to coloured.

```
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <div className={classes.profile}>
                <div className="img-collection">
                    <Tooltip title="Recieve 20 likes" arrow>
                        <div className="achievement">
                            <img className={`${likeBadgeActive ? "active" : ""}`} src={Fire} alt="monkey" />
                            <h5>Noble</h5>
                        </div>
                    </Tooltip>
                    <Tooltip title="Receive 10 comments" arrow>
                        <div className="achievement">
                            <img className={`${commentBadgeActive ? "active" : ""}`} src={Scholar} alt="monkey" />
                            <h5>Scholar</h5>
                        </div>
                    </Tooltip>
                    <Tooltip title="Upload 10 memes" arrow>
                        <div className="achievement">
                            <img className={`${screamCountActive ? "active" : ""}`} src={Knight} alt="monkey" />
                            <h5>Contributor</h5>
                        </div>
                    </Tooltip>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Paper>
```

**Styling**

```
 "& .img-collection": {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",


        "& .achievement": {
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",


            "& img": {
                height: 70,
                filter: 'grayscale(100%)'
            },

            "& active": {
                height: 70,
                filter: 'grayscale(0%) !important'
            },

        },
    },
```

**Logging commentBadgeActive**

```
  const {
    classes,
    totalXP,
    userLevel,
    screamCountActive,
    commentBadgeActive,
    likeBadgeActive,
    profile: { handle, createdAt, imageUrl, bio, website, location, nativeLanguage, learnLanguage }
} = props;

console.log(commentBadgeActive);
```

The log statement returns **true** but the `active` class doesn't get applied to the image

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you forgot to add `.` before  `active` class:

```
"& .img-collection": {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",


        "& .achievement": {
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",


            "& img": {
                height: 70,
                filter: 'grayscale(100%)'
            },

            "& .active": {
                height: 70,
                filter: 'grayscale(0%) !important'
            },

        },
    },
```